# Cannot write HSSFWorkbook to ByteArray and then read it to HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, stream, arrays, apache-poi

5i need to convert a HSSFWorkbook (Apache's POI) to an ByteArray and later to convert the ByteArray back to the HSSFWorkbook. The following TestCase illustrates my problem:

```
   @Test
   public void testXLSExportImport(){
      try {
         InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FILEPATH);
         HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
         byte[] exported = wb.getBytes();
         HSSFWorkbook wb2 = new HSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(exported)); 
         //in the line above the exception is thrown
      } catch (Exception e) {
         assertTrue(false);
      }
   }
```

the testcase fails with the exception: java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0005060000100809, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0

(I am using Apaches POI 3.5-beta3)

I hope somebody can help me... how can I get it work?!

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of POI?  Although I'm not sure, I'd bet updating would at least help.  The most recent stable version is 3.9.

Comment: because I also use an old primefaces version :(...updating it would be a lot of work and can't be done by now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not writing the workbook correctly! You need to use the [write(Outputstream)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) call.

As shown in the [various examples on the website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api), your code should instead be:

```
     InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FILEPATH);
     HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     wb.write(out);
     HSSFWorkbook wb2 = new HSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

Also, don't open a Workbook from a FileInputStream, if you have a File use that directly. Opening from a File [uses less memory than from a Stream](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream).